# Is there any bootstrapping template to build apps that look like Visual Studio Code

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, electron

I want to build an app that looks like Visual Studio code. Is there any template or ui library that I can use as a starting point? The look that I want to achieve is like shown in the image [image]

I am suspecting there must be a starter template as Microsoft is using the same look across apps, to name a few: VS Code, Botframework Emulator v4, Microsoft SQL Operations Studio.

Comment: Do you mean auto populate hint? like how VS is showing functions name?

Comment: I mean which components. I can use to build app that my app will be like vs code. For exiample. If i wrote app foк win I would use https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/ but which UI component I can use with electron

Comment: It's built on Electron (https://electronjs.org/) and in electron uses HTML,JS,JQUERY,ANGULAR JS components. Have you tried to implement sample application using Electron platform?

Comment: I am lookin for somthing like http://photonkit.com/ but look like VS code

Comment: Here is a [electron-vscode-boilerplate](https://github.com/Jesper-Hustad/electron-vscode-boilerplate)

Comment: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/  Monaco Editor is the open-source plugin created by Microsoft, which is used in VsCode.

Answer (score 4):

VS Code does not use an external UI component library; the UI is built from a small  internal library of composable components.

Please [browse through the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) if you are interested in seeing how all of this is implemented. Keep in mind that the UI code is often quite VS code specific. While it is fairly easily to modify these components in VS Code, it would generally not be worth the effort to extract these components for use in an external app.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you need to show functionality to auto-populate hints, same like how visual studio showing all functions name in above picture.

Then for this, you can use Twitter open source API, please follow below link which shows various options

> https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

For rest of the functionality, of course, you need to implement HTML design for that.

Comment: I suspect the OP is looking for a UI framework/toolkit like Element-UI.  I got the impression they were interested in how to do the TreeView, the Splitter, the NavBar and Menus, etc.  All can be done from scratch in HTML/CSS/JS, but that would be a huge pain if there are packages like Element that get the job done more efficiently.